# Not sure about leaving brand new job for another.

Tags: new-job, resignation

I have been unemployed since Xmas 2014. I took voluntary redundancy because the company I worked for at the time was putting me in a very stressful situation and not really giving any indication that improvements might be on the horizon. 
In the year I was unemployed I have plenty of interviews.  In early October 2015 I found a company I liked,  the interview went well and I was given a conditional offer within a couple of weeks.  I was very happy and excited thinking I'd be working within a couple of weeks. Sadly the company took their sweet time giving me any further information.  I had to get a health clearance but they were very uncommunicative and I barely heard anything until late Jan 2016.
Because I was on JSA during this time I had to keep looking for and applying for jobs in the meantime despite knowing I had a job.  I was just waiting, waiting, waiting to find out! 
Eventually I started on Feb 22nd. I like the people but all of the same identical issues exist from my old job plus I really don't like very many things about my office,  working style and organization of daily tasks. I figured I'd get used to it though the first week I was extremely disappointed indeed. 
Last week I got an offer of interview with one of the places I applied to during my wait over Xmas. It looks to me like I have a very good chance of getting this role and that the working style/office etc is much more suited to me.  The money is slightly less but the commute is so much better.

My question is,  if this second job wants me and I like them,  what is the correct procedure to follow in this case? I am expected to give a weeks notice,  however as this is a technical role it seems to me rather pointless that they would have me sitting in the office for an extra week of shadowing as I am still too new to do anything but watch and learn.

I felt nervous about the first job as they took so long to hire me and I was very irritated by being left hanging for almost four months. But if this other role offers me peace and a better run work environment I will be very tempted to take it,  if for nothing other than my sanity.

What is my best plan of action,  I haven't been given the other job yet,  but if they did give me an offer after next week,  how should I proceed?

Comment: Take the job that's going to suit you best and make you happy.  You can't stay at a job just because it might piss off the bosses since you just started.  That won't help you at all.  If the new job seems like a better fit, that's the one you should take, end of story.

Comment: This is getting advice close votes and I can see why with the way it's worded. I think there's a useful question in here though (or I wouldn't have answered). If this ends up closed it could use a bit of editing to bring it on point.

Comment: What if the new job also bothers you? Maybe working in an office isn't your thing :/

Answer (score 2):

You seem awful waffly on what you want.  If this new offer is better than the job you are in now then take it.  I would make sure that this new offer is set in stone and I would make sure that you have a start day within a week before telling current company.  If it is a month out or more I would simply keep working at current company until you are sure that you are going into the next job.

As for the conversation, you talk to your boss and get ready to leave.  As you said this isn't a good situation, you have cost this company time, resources, and money.  They don't want you there and may ask you to leave right away.  I seriously suggest taking all personal items home in a subtle way before this conversation.

I also would not try to get current company bidding for you.  Once you tell them this and they do bid more and you stay - they will drop you so fast it isn't funny the first issue they have with you.

**Also take your picture off this site when you are asking a question like this.**

Answer (score 0):

Deciding on the best course of action is something only you can do. We can only guide your thinking. I'd normally recommend against abandoning an employer but **at the end of the day you have to do what's best for you** and that might just mean burning a bridge with your current company. If they left you hanging for 4 months then that certainly hasn't given them any credit.

If you accept the new offer, go to your manager at your current company. Explain that while you realise this isn't ideal, you kept interviewing while you were waiting for the paperwork to clear, you got an opportunity that you can't turn down and have chosen to resign. Give them your week's notice but offer to leave immediately if they prefer. Acknowledge how much of an inconvenience this is but remain professional. Don't mention or entertain counter offers. I'd recommend against mentioning where you're going and hold off on updating your LinkedIn or social media profile. There are occasional reports of bad employers who react poorly in a situation like this and try to blacken your name with your new company. It's incredibly unlikely to happen but there's no point in risking it.

It's up to you if you want to disclose your current company to the new company. I probably wouldn't. If you do, make it clear to the new company that this was an exceptional circumstance and you're looking to stay with them for the long-term. In the UK I'd probably throw in some criticism of the inane [JSA](https://www.gov.uk/jobseekers-allowance/overview) laws to shift some blame.